# Apply geo distance filter on nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

My mapping contains a nested field like this:

```
"Locations": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "GeoPoint": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is store some additional attributes with every location of the document.

Unfortunately, it looks like this won't work with a [geo distance filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html):

```
GET /myIndex/myType/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "100 mi",
      "Locations.GeoPoint": {
        lat: 40.70,
        lon: -74.00
      }
    }
  }
}
```

won't return the any results, whereas the filter works flawlessly if the GeoPoint is directly on the document itself instead of on the nested field:

```
GET /myIndex/myType/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "100 mi",
      "GeoPoint": {
        lat: 40.70,
        lon: -74.00
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make geo distance filter work with geo_point on the nested field?

Answer (score 4):

A [nested filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html) does the job:

```
GET /myIndex/myType/_search
{
  "filter" : {
    "nested" : {
      "path" : "Locations",
      "filter" : {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "100 mi",
          "GeoPoint": {
            "lat": 40.70,
            "lon": -74.00
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An update for ElasticSearch 5.5 users, @Max's answer has been deprecated for the Nested Filter and Nested Query feature using the dot notation instead of explicitly wrapping a "nested" field around your query.

For example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "obj1",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"obj1.name" : "blue"} },
                    { "range" : {"obj1.count" : {"gt" : 5}} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html